# Addition of asymmetrical uncertainties for use in KDE?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, asymmetrical

My data have asymmetrical confidence intervals (e.g. 100 with a 95% lower bound of 50 and 95% upper bound of 300). I want to perform a KDE on all my data where the bandwidth is determined by the uncertainty. However, the uncertainties are asymmetrical so it is not as simple as using a weighted mean. Does anybody know how to add asymmetrical uncertainties, and perform KDE using the summed uncertainty?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is (very) asymmetrical the single bandwith kde can under/over smooth the density depending on the location. I have read briefily on variable bandiwth kde algorithms that could be solution you need. [This stackoverflow question] talks about this and the top answer points some python implementations that do this. There are implementations for other languages.

Note that is not just because your data is somewhat asymmetrical that kde is not adequate or will not estimate an useful distribution. An evaluation process should be done to decide wheter or not that is the case.

Comment: Just realized I didn't link the stackoverflow question. Sorry., here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483625/adaptive-bandwidth-kernel-density-estimation

Comment: Thank you. I have multiple independent measurements of a value, X, where each value has its associated upper and lower confidence bound (which are asymmetrical). So some values of X have less asymmetrically distributed confidence intervals while others are very asymmetrical. I want to plot a KDE which represents the distribution of all values of X, where the bandwidth is determined by the uncertainty in my measurements. However this requires summing all of the asymmetrical uncertainties, since the resulting KDE is the sum of probabilities for all values of X, right? Thanks so much again

Comment: I don't understand. You have a 1-dimesion variable X and multiple independent measurements of X, right? Something like x1, x2, x3, ..., xn, each a single number. Or each measurement comes with a confidence bound (in which case x1, x2, x3,..., xn are all triples of numbers (value, lower conf bound, upper conf bound)? If it is the second case, you could do something as perform the KDE algorithm to a set of samples that are originated on random samples made inside the confidence interval for each measurement.

Comment: Yes, second case. Thank you